# Convert jar to C# dll using IKVM - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, ikvm

i am using IKVM to convert a java jar file to a c# dll.
This jar file has several dependencies, which i referenced all via -r:reference.dll .

Still im getting the following warning and i dont know how to get rid of it:

```
IKVM.NET Compiler version 7.2.4630.5
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Jeroen Frijters
http://www.ikvm.net/

warning IKVMC0111: Emitted java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in "myproject.myclass.setFocus()V"
("org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control")
```

The command i am converting the jarfile is:

```
ikvmc -target:library -debug -out:project.dll -r:org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.5.2.v3557f.dll -r:severalmoreherretofollow project.jar 2> project.log
```

The class "org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control" is declared inside the "org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.5.2.v3557f.dll" which had no errors when compiling it with ikvm to a dll.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile more as one jar file then it can be recommended to compile it in one step. See the [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Convert_a_jar_file_to_a_dll_and_use_it_as_library) for more details. This prevent you from circulate dependencies.

I think you need to use a full qualified file name with the -r option.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I compiled all jars with -sharedclassloader flag enabled in one step. Now this message is gone. BTW: relative paths are possible

Comment: can we give .jar in reference?

Comment: Updated link: https://sourceforge.net/p/ikvm/wiki/ClassNotFoundException/